# Не находит строку (StreamReader)

Tags: c#

У меня скачан html файл в котором есть такая строка:

```
<img class="channel-header-profile-image" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l79-AEcvYhx5x6ZgY3f6XzsyV_jOtDKJkI0IYg=s100-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no" title="carykh" alt="carykh">
```

(Это одна строка)
Мне надо найти её и получить из этой строки только ссылку.
Я пытался так:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default))
{
    label6.Text = file;
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != "</body></html>")
    {
        label6.Text = line;
        if(line.Contains(@"<img class=\""channel - header - profile - image\"" src=\"""""""))
        {
            htmlimage.Add(line.Replace(@"<img class=\""channel - header - profile - image\"" src=\""""""", "").Replace(@" title = """"carykh"""" alt = """"carykh"""" > ", ""));
        }
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

Но это не давало результатов.

Comment: Если вы работаете с HTML файлом, почему бы не разбрать его инструментами, предназначенными для разбора HTML? Например, [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/).

Comment: `channel - header - profile - image` - здесь у вас пробелы вокруг знаков `-`. А в другом месте пробелов нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил Проблему.

```
            foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\TESTER\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MFG\MFG\bin\Debug\youtube.com\user"))
            {
                var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                document.Load(file);
                foreach(var node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img [@class=\"channel-header-profile-image\"]"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(node.Attributes["src"].Value);
                }
            }
```